# Calculating the maximum basis voltage of an transistor

Tags: transistors

I'm having problem with calculating this parameter, I have to calculate the maximum basis voltage of transistor for power amp with complementary transistors. So I know Uebmax(maximum emitter-basis voltage) I have this formula:

```
Ubmax = Uebmax - Uebrest
Ubmax - maximum basis voltage
Uebmax - maximum emiter-basis voltage (I have this value)
Uebrest - emiter-basis voltage when the transistor is in rest(there is voltage and current in the schematic but there isn't signal which to amplify).
```

From where I can get Uebrest ?

Schematic (not the best quality but it's still understandable):

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Do you have a schematic you can post?

Comment: basis = base. Also, the text you have highlighted - is this some form of quote. If so can you provide a link?

Comment: http://www62.zippyshare.com/v/62732615/file.html Here is the schematic, I didn't find it in Internet .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For silicon bipolar transistors you may assume that Uebrest is approximately 0.7 volts. From the facts you have presented it is not possible to calculate this. If you want to analyse your circuit by logic reasoning, assuming 0.7 volts for emitter/base is a good help. However, if your only goal is the calculation of Uebrest itself... sorry, can't help.

I've got a sneaking suspicion that you are not able to express your real problem, at least it seems that you don't understand what I am trying to say. A practical approach to transistor usage is that the arrow on the symbol is the emitter, and current only flows in the direction of the arrow between collector and emitter. The current will also only flow if the emitter-base voltage is above 0.7 volts (rule of thumb), the lowest potensial being at the arrows end. Base voltage should also be less than collector voltage for PNP (arrow pointing out), or base voltage greater than Collector voltage for NPN (arrow pointing in).

Generally you use collector for voltage amplification (inverted output) and emitter for current amplification. Your circuit resembles an amplifier, but the transistors are not set up correctly. It seems to me that you have put the NPN transistors in "up-side-down". That probably why you are having trouble.

Comment: Is this the only way you know. I have some other parameters, So if you know anything other I will be very grateful

Comment: Yea, sorry, too long since my student days. These kind of academic excercises aren't really useful in real life electrical engingeering unless you are actually making semiconductors. The Uebrest parameter is usually given in datasheets, but as mentioned above, you can analyse your circuit trusting that is is 0.7 volts, give or take. This is the very fundamental property of the transistir that makes it so useful in analogue designs, just like you are doing here. So you may get the Uebrest from a datasheet, or use 0.7 volts. The academics behind it is past my domain.

Comment: I have analyse my circuit Uebrest = 0.15 V and  Uebmax = 0.35 V Ubm = 0.20V. Thanks for trying to help